# Why must you call SelectObject before calling GetTextExtendPoint32

Tags: visual-c++

I understand that for GetTextExtendPoint32 to work correctly, it needs to know the correct font.  However, I'm confused as to why SelectObject needs to be called.  Example I wanted to calc the length of the text for a check box.

Works:

```
Size sizeChkBox;
CString csChkBox;
m_ChxBox.GetWindowText(csChkBox);
CDC* dc = m_ChkBox.GetDC();
HFONT hfontChK = (HFONT)GetWindowFont(m_ChkBox.GetSafeHwnd());
SelectObject(*dc, hfontChK);
GetTextExtentPoint32(*dc, csChkBox, strlen(csChkBox), &sizeChkBox);
```

Doesn't Work:

```
Size sizeChkBox;
CString csChkBox;
m_ChxBox.GetWindowText(csChkBox);
CDC* dc = m_ChkBox.GetDC();
GetTextExtentPoint32(*dc, csChkBox, strlen(csChkBox), &sizeChkBox);
```

I guess my question really is why doesn't dc have the correct font already since its "made from the checkbox"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetDC(HWND)` creates an `HDC` with all default settings, set up for drawing on a given window. It doesn't actually interrogate the window for its properties: in particular, it doesn't send `WM_GETFONT` to it.

Realize that `WM_SETFONT` and `WM_GETFONT` work only by convention. Nothing says that a window must handle these messages, or use the font provided in its `WM_PAINT` implementation. Standard controls tend to do this, as a common courtesy, but this is by no means a universal requirement.